# getting the value of a target_id

Tags: views, hooks

Using either **node_load_multiple** or **entity_metadata_wrapper**, how do you go about getting the value of a target_id? Using Views does not seem to work either because of the target_id value does not get pulled in by the hook_cron().

for a value, you can use something like

```
$node = node_load($value->nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$userId1 = $wrapper->field_name->value();
```

Using noad_load_multiple, I get an array like

```
Array
(
[595796] => stdClass Object
(
...
[field_name] => Array
(
[und] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[target_id] => 1010101
...
```

The goal is to get the target_id so that I can create a node with that value, creating the node is not the problem.

I also tried variations of

```
$foo_foo = node_load_multiple(array_keys($foo_foo_result['node']));    
$foo = current($foo_foo['node']['field_name']['und'][0]['target_id']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume You are using drupal 7 
if so you result is an object:

```
$foo_foo = node_load_multiple(array_keys($foo_foo_result['node']));
$target_ids = [];
foreach ($foo_foo as $result) {
   $target_id = $result->field_name['und'][0]['target_id'];
   $target_ids[] = $target_id;
}
var_dump($target_id);
die('stop');
```

In Drupal 8 its WAY WAY WAY easier then this.